# How to "for loop" in J

Tags: j

I tried but the code wont work.

```
for.     T do. B end.
for_xyz. T do. B end.
```

What would be the equivalent of this from C#

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
```

And what's a good keyword to Google for J problems?

Comment: Googling "J" indeed is irritating! Found a shortcut to the right content?

Comment: Try restricting your search to specific sites, e.g. `site:jsoftware.com foo` (Google) or `!so [j] foo` (DuckDuckGo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted at the beginning of [the Control Structures section](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/ctrl.htm), these only apply within Explicit definition. The colon is the key for setting up such a script. The only time 'for.' (or any similar word) can occur is within a script determined by the right parameter to `:` , i.e. colon, meaning [Explicit](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d310n.htm).

Use [the link](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/cfor.htm) on the control-word `for.` on that page to find complete samples. Notice that these special symbols (such as for. and end.) normally occur in multi-line scripts that end with a single lone right-paren. That sort of structure is what you must use if you're to use control words.

Here is the first of the examples given on the Dictionary page documenting the `for.` structure (http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/cfor.htm):

```
f0=. 3 : 0
 s=. 0
 for. i. y do. s=. >:s end.
)
```

Once you have arranged control words inside this sort of structure, they take effect when the script is executed. In this example, when the verb `f0` receives an integer as its only (right) parameter (referred to as `y` in the script) it results in the same integer. It iterates through the for loop to arrive at that number.

Comment: If my code doesn't run, I'll have to re-type everything right? So is there a complier similar to other languages like C# for example that I can run as many times as I want while retaining my code.

Comment: I recommend putting such scripts into files that you can edit and load. One introduction to that is here:http://jsoftware.com/help/learning/04.htm If you are using a windowed application as your environment, look under the File menu for New ijs When you are in a .ijs file window, look under the Run menu for Window and Window Display. I find it much easier to work with multi-line scripts through .ijs files.

Comment: Could you explain the f0 function for multiple output lines? When I did it only returned s once. But in their [.for](http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/cfor.htm) section they have more complex operations returning multiple lines. For example in the OP's case it would be something like `for. i.10 do. s=. >:s end.` But this only returns the last result (I think or it only returns one result)

Comment: @PhilippeHarewood: J functions work like C functions: they can return only one result (with the added difference that J functions cannot *not* return anything). J functions will return the last evaluated item (`s` in the case above). The returned result can be anything, a single value, an array, a matrix...

Comment: @MPelletier I don't know because the link I posted above shows functions that return multiple lines maybe it returns one output but there are multiple as it stands I cannot convert the op c# to j. The for loop should execute the operation many times, what about display 'hello' ?

Comment: Yes, the verb returns only the value of the final expression computed before ending. Verbs are typically like mathematical functions: only the ultimate value is visible to the world outside the definition. However, you may produce an effect on the side. The handy thing for this is smoutput. Take a look at the "Execution" section of the following wiki page for examples of smoutput in use: http://www.jsoftware.com/jwiki/Scripts/Prolog#execution

Comment: @PhilippeHarewood: I see what you mean. What @kaleidic says is right on the money: what you're seeing in the above function is the result. If you want the function to write something at each step, make it do that with `smoutput`. It's like `Console.WriteLine`.

Comment: Philippe, I had not understood your question. You noted "But in their [examples] they have more complex operations returning multiple lines." This is done is by producing a result that displays over multiple lines. It is still a single result. (Contrast this with the multiple-effects per execution you obtain if you use `smoutput` within a loop.) How many lines get printed depends on the shape (and atomic type) of the result. For simple examples of integer arrays, if the result of the verb is a (two axis) table, this will be displayed with each row of the table on a separate line.

Answer (score 4):

A more J-ish way to loop is using [Power](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d202n.htm) `^:`, this

```
f^:10 y
```

will apply `f` 10 times; first to `y`, then to `f(y)`, ... :

```
f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(f(y))))))))))
```

So if `p` is a print function, eg: `p =: (4) 1!:2~ ]`:

```
(p^:10) 'Hello World!'
Hello World!Hello World!...
```

In general J (in a way) promotes loop-less code. If you really needed 10 times the string 'Hello World!' for example, you probably would do something like:

```
10 12 $ 'Hello World!'
Hello World!
Hello World!
Hello World!
...
```